# (Why) are Deligne-Lusztig varieties nonempty?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, deligne-lusztig-theory

**Background**: Let $G$ be a reductive $\mathbb F_q$-group and let $X$ be the variety of Borel subgroups of $G$. By the Bruhat decomposition, the $G$-orbits in the space $X\times X$ (with diagonal action) are indexed by elements $w$ of the universal Weyl group $W$ of $G$. Let $\cal O(w)$ be the orbit corresponding to $w$. The *Deligne-Lusztig variety* $X(w)$ is defined to be the intersection of $\cal O(w)$ with the graph of the Frobenius endomorphism of $X$.

Deligne and Lusztig argue that $X(w)$ is of pure dimension $\ell(w)$, the length of $w$, by a transversality argument. My question is about this argument. I assume the argument to be standard, since Deligne and Lusztig devote only a sentence to it, but there's one point I'm having trouble with.

Two subvarieties of an ambient variety are transverse at a point $x$ if the sum of their tangent spaces at $x$ generates the ambient tangent space. When $x$ is a point of transversality, there is a formula for the codimension of the intersection of the varieties (near $x$): it is the sum of the codimensions of the subvarieties.

Since Frobenius has derivative zero, any intersection point of $\cal O(w)$ and the graph of Frobenius is a point of transversality. It follows (by the previous paragraph and the formula for the dimension of $\cal O(w)$) that if $\cal O(w)$ and the graph of Frobenius intersect, then their intersection, the Deligne-Lusztig variety $X(w)$, has pure dimension $\ell(w)$.

**Question**: (Why) does $\cal O(w)$ intersect the graph of Frobenius at all? In other words, (why) is the Deligne-Lusztig variety $X(w)$ non-empty?

**Additional thoughts**: It's easy to see that $X(1) = X(\mathbb F_q)\neq\varnothing$. Using the dimension estimate, you can also show that $X(w_0)\neq\varnothing$, where $w_0$ is the longest element of $W$: indeed, $X(w_0)$ is a dense subvariety of $X$. However, I don't see how to conclude from formal properties of the Bruhat stratification and the dimension estimate that the intersection must be nonempty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\newcommand\FF{\overline{\mathbb F}}\DeclareMathOperator\Fr{Fr}$The Lang (or Lang–Steinberg) map $G(\FF) \to G(\FF)$ given by $g \mapsto g^{-1}\Fr(g)$ is surjective.  In particular, there is some $g \in G(\FF)$ such that $g^{-1}\Fr(g)$ represents $w$.  If $B$ is a rational Borel containing the reference torus, then $g B_{\FF} g^{-1}$ and $\Fr(g B_{\FF} g^{-1})$ are in relative position $w$.

Comment: Thanks Loren! You are always answering my questions :D

Comment: @DavidSchwein, no problem!  My understanding of DL varieties is very small, so I'm glad to find an occasional question I can answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwein, by the way, surjectivity of the LS map is used all over; but one of my favourite applications of a different but related principle (Lemma 7.3) is used in the proof of Theorem 7.2 of [Steinberg - Endomorphisms of linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/memo/0080), which states that every surjective endomorphism of a linear algebraic group $G$ over an algebraically closed field preserves a Borel subgroup of $G$.

Comment: That's a very nice result. I suppose that once you know Theorem 7.2, you can begin to understand these endomorphisms through their effect on pinnings and so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwein, before you can get the most out of a result about fixing Borels (e.g., by talking about roots), it turns out that you need to make sure you also fix a maximal torus *within* the Borel, and that is *not* automatic.  The endomorphisms (or maybe just automorphisms, I forget—I only think of automorphisms) that do this are called "quasisemisimple", because they generalise semisimple automorphisms, i.e., those that arise by conjugation by a semisimple element in some overgroup.

Comment: Ah, I see. So one particular point here is that conjugation by a unipotent element preserves a Borel, but not necessarily a maximal torus.

Comment: @DavidSchwein, [indeed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428891/why-are-deligne-lusztig-varieties-nonempty/428892#comment1103420_428892); an inner automorphism of a connected reductive group (over an algebraically closed field) is quasisemisimple if and only if it is semisimple.  In particular, conjugation by a unipotent element of such a group *never* preserves a maximal torus (unless the unipotent element is trivial).